# Howto: install JOGL for Eclipse in Mac OSX 10.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, osx-snow-leopard, jogl

I got Snow Leopard 64 bit, and I'm wondering how I am to install JOGL in order to develop with Eclipse.

A nice tut from A-Z would have been nice, since I'm suspecting some of my steps are very wrong.

--Edit: 28.aug.2012--

JOGL 1.1 is only compatible with Java JDK 1.6 not JDK 1.7. Tested on OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Download [jogl](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.1.1a/jogl-1.1.1a-macosx-universal.zip)
2. Create a new project, and unzip the lib folder from the file you downloaded into the project.
3. Add the jogl.jar and gluegen-rt.jar to the build path. Right click jogl.jar in the package explorer in the build path. Click "Properties", and set the "Native Libraries" option to point to the same lib folder that should also contains four *.jnilib files.

Comment: Thanks!

I only had to do one thing first: 
Right click on jogl.jar > "Build Path" > "Add to Build Path".
From there I could right click on jogl.jar under "Referenced Libraries" and do step 3.

Comment: Also note that the linked version of JOGL is 1.1.1a. It is the latest 1.x version but you might want to use JOGL 2.x depending on your needs. If you do use 2.x, you will need to include four of the libraries - jogl.all.jar, glugen-rt.jar, nativewindow.all.jar, and newt.all.jar. Otherwise same instructions. Link to 2.0-beta10: http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-2.0-beta10/jogl-2.0-macosx-universal.zip

Comment: JOGL 1.1.x is only compatible with Java JDK 1.6, not JDK 1.7. More description in the question field.

Comment: Ricket, you misspelled gluegen-rt.jar and I advise other developers to look at our official wiki which is really up-to-date: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_project

Comment: Obsolete version, obsolete steps. Rather look at xranby's answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using JogAmp JOGL 2 you only need to include jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar to your project. All the macos x specific native jars will be automatically found at runtime if they are located next to the jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar 
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL